# Mongodb Query Cache

Tags: mongodb, database

Scenario:  Our DB is huge (~20 tb of data) and we keep adding data daily.  We'd like to create a webpage that users can see that interacts with our db by showing certain data aggregates.  It's too slow to query (or do mapreduce) in real time.  So we end up creating a data cache of pre-calculated aggregates and incrementally update it daily.

Is there any current library or software that would sit on mongodb that already handles this?  Is there a better known way to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with your solution? "Find a library or software" questions aren't good fits for StackOverflow. You're apparently running standardized queries and caching the results periodically. That seems very typical, and any solution would be specific to the rest of your infrastructure, which you did not describe.

Comment: Well, I didn't mean that's the only way.  This is what I came up with (and I'm happy to use it), but I just wanted to see what other people are doing...

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue and we solved it by using [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/) (in memory data grid) to process data on the fly and store them into DB. Hazelcast doesn't have specific MongoDB integration but it works pretty good in our situation. Hazelcast has MapStore implementation where you can set a Relational/NoSql DB as a map store and it will store data into the DB in a given period. It has good configuration file where you can configure ttl, number of backups, merge policy and etc.

For more information check following documents:

- [Hazelcast MapStore](http://www.hazelcast.com/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/MapStore.html)
- [Distributed Map](http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/3.0/manual/single_html/#Map)